# Algorithm to compress a very short string

Tags: compression

I am trying to compress a code for a project, that use [a-z], [0-9], [A-Z], @ and & as possible characters. Normally the code has the following format:

```
g&w9gMaaaaadHjNMa5@
g0m3q6aaaaadHjNMM5@
hsV7YaaaaaadHjNNq5@
```

What is the algorithm that provides the best compress rate (for this case)?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry. There are three diferents codes in the sample above. (g&w9gMaaaaadHjNMa5@,  g0m3q6aaaaadHjNMM5@ and hsV7YaaaaaadHjNNq5@).

Comment: There are repeated "a" in all? There is also either "N" or "M" consecutively? Those can be simplified if that is the case. They all always end with a number also? Do you know which algorithm produces them?

Comment: I don't know about the generation algorithm (it's proprietary). I have noticed that the repeted "a" is in all codes. I have tried to compact it cutting these character, but I need to know is there is a better algorithm.